# Looping over dictionary

Tags: python, directory

My Code :

```
prices = {"banana": 4,"apple": 2,"orange": 1.5,"pear": 3}
stock = {"banana": 6,"apple": 0,"orange": 32,"pear": 15,}
for i in prices:
    print i
    print "price : %s" % prices[i]
    print "stock : %s" % stock[i]
```

My Output is:

```
orange
price : 1.5
stock : 32
pear
price : 3
stock : 15
banana
price : 4
stock : 6
apple
price : 2
stock : 0
None
```

My question is why my output is printed from "orange" rather than "banana " then "apple then "orange: then "pear"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python dicts are unordered, that is their keys are not in lexicographical sorting. If you want the keys to be always ordered, use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead. Otherwise, you can also sort the list and instead use `for i in sorted(prices):`.

Comment: In My example what my understanding is :
for first loop 
print i is equal to print banana
print "price : %s" % prices[i] is equal to prices[banana] # Value of key'Banana'

stock[i] is equal to stock[banana] 
is this understanding incorrect?

Comment: @Govindchouhan Yes that is correct. When you iterate over a dictionary, you are basically iterating over its `keys`. Since the keys are same in both the dicts, you can easily access the values using `dictionary[key]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to work with order dictionaries, then [orderdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) would be perfect for you:

```
prices = {"banana": 4,"apple": 2,"orange": 1.5,"pear": 3}

stock = {"banana": 6, "apple": 0, "orange": 32,"pear": 15}

from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter

prices1 = OrderedDict(sorted(prices.items(), key = itemgetter(0)))
stock1  = OrderedDict(sorted(stock.items() , key = itemgetter(0)))

#print(list(prices1.keys()))

for i in prices1:
    print(i)
    print("price : %s" % prices1[i])
    print("stock : %s" % stock1[i])

print(prices1)    
print(stock1)
```

This gives:

```
apple
price : 2
stock : 0
banana
price : 4
stock : 6
orange
price : 1.5
stock : 32
pear
price : 3
stock : 15
OrderedDict([('apple', 2), ('banana', 4), ('orange', 1.5), ('pear', 3)])
OrderedDict([('apple', 0), ('banana', 6), ('orange', 32), ('pear', 15)])
```

Answer (score 0):

`dict`s in Python are not ordered.

You could [sort](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) they keys first and then use them:

```
for i in sorted(prices): # sorts the keys
    print i
    print "price : %s" % prices[i]
    print "stock : %s" % stock[i]
```

To print alphabetically.

You could also use your own custom sort key like:

```
for i in sorted(prices, key=str.lower): # sorts the keys disregarding case
    print i
    print "price : %s" % prices[i]
    print "stock : %s" % stock[i]
```

### Edit:

If you need a [ordered dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), there is an implementation of one in the collections library.

Comment: i want it to print directory values in the same order in which they are stored, using sorted will make it print in alphabetical order.